# Use tf.exe to create a workspace

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfvc

Can someone help me with creating a workspace from tf.exe commandline?
I'm trying to setup a workspace for VS Code to use, and can't install VS, so I have copied the tf.exe files and prereq dll's and tried the following:

```
TF.exe vc workspace /new IIS-VM-WorkSpace /collection:https://<AzureRepo>
```

But I get an you har not authorized error.
I have tried to add `/login:<mye-mail>` but it doesn't change anything.

How can I log in to a tf workspace?

Comment: What did you enter after `/login`? Looks like this may be from a non-domain joined VM to a domain joined TFS server, in which case the format may make a difference (and the domain configuration may be blocking the auth completely). Try `/login:user@domain,password` and  `/login:domain\user,password`.

Comment: It's also possible your user name must be enclosed in quotes: `"/login:user"` or `/login:"user"`.

Comment: Or that specific client certificate auth or kerberos configuration is needed `tf vc certificates` will allow you to configure that bit.

Comment: It's a Azure joined machine connecting to Azure DevOps.
I have tried different variations with the " but nothing works.
Have tried to change to "Provide no certificate" but still the same

Comment: For Azure devops you'll need to use `/login:.,personalaccesstoken`

Comment: Of course replace personalaccesstoken with your own PAT.

Comment: Still error, but it  might be the URL that is wrong.
I'm using: https://<tennant>.visualstudio.com/<Project>
I have also tried https://<tennant>.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/<Project>
But I get 404 not found.
Can I see which URL I should use somewhere?

Comment: I expect you need to not put in the project name at all. Workspace are bound to the projectcollection level in tfs and organisation level in Azure devops.

Comment: I think you are right. I have just been looking in settings, and found that I can use the new domain `https://dev.azure.com/<tenant>` and this URL I use now, but I still get the `TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://dev.azure.com/<tenant>`

Comment: How did you obtain the PAT?

Comment: Loggin in to dev.azure.com pressing my profile picture going to security and "add token"
Just to verify, I use this command i powershell: `TF.exe workspace /new $Name /collection:$URL /login:$Username,$PAT`

Comment: Instead ot username use `. `

Comment: What I am wondering is why you aren't receiving a auth pop-up, maybe you haven't copied enough

Comment: Spot on, I missed some files, so after copying the who Team Explorer folder, I get a login box.
Now I just need to figure out which file I can safely delete :)

Thank you very much!